# Implementing search bar for an Array retrieved from database in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery .I have an Object which i have retrieved from the database and i need to implement search on it.

```
 $("#search-box").on("keyup", function searchnew() {
        var g = $(this).val();
        $(".dropdown.search-groups a").each( function() {
        var s = $(this).text();
        if (s.indexOf(g)!=-1) {
        $(this).parent().parent().show();
        }
        else {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        }
        });
```

The corresponding code in html is:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="search-box" data-provide="typeahead" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="height:30px;" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  <td><button type="submit" id="search-button" onclick="searchnew()" class="btn btn-default"> <!-- onClick="window.location = document.getElementById('search-box').value;"-->Go</button></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

<div class="other-groups">
            <%
                // Contains list of groups present in the organization
                Object group[][]=groupBean.getGroup_details();
                Integer i;
                System.out.println("in dashboard before groups");
                if(group!=null){
                for(i=0;i<group.length;i++){
            %>
            <div>
                <ul>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <li class="dropdown" style="width:100%;"><div class="search-groups"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="search-<%=i %>" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;"
        data-toggle="dropdown" ><%=group[i][1]%><span class="caret"></span></a></div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" >

        <li><a title="View and Manage All Voice Messages"
                        <% out.print("href='IvrsServlet?groupId="+group[i][0]+"&req_type=voiceMessage' target='right-iframe'"); %>>Voice Message Response<br>(आवाज संदेश प्रतिक्रिया)
                    </a></li>                           
                    <li><a title="Broadcast Voice/Text Messages"
                        <% out.print("href=IvrsServlet?req_type=voice&group_id="+group[i][0]+" target='right-iframe'"); %>>Broadcast<br>(प्रसारण)
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a title="Manage Call/Members of Group"
                        <% out.print("href='IvrsServlet?groupId="+group[i][0]+"&req_type=manage' target='right-iframe'"); %>>Manage<br>(प्रबंधित)
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a title="View and Manage All Text Messages"
                        <% out.print("href='IvrsServlet?groupId="+group[i][0]+"&req_type=textMessage' target='right-iframe'"); %>>Text Message Response<br>(पाठ संदेश प्रतिक्रिया)
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a title="View all Outgoing Text Messages of Group"
                        <% out.print("href='IvrsServlet?groupId="+group[i][0]+"&req_type=outgoingMessage' target='right-iframe'"); %>>Outgoing SMS<br>(जाने वाले संदेश)
                    </a></li>

            </ul>
        </li></ul>
    </div>
     <%     }// end of for loop
                }// end of if condition
            %>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But this is not helping me .what else should i do ?

Comment: You just need `$(this).parent().show();` to access the `li` one more parent will point to `ul`

Comment: @sabithpocker i did that it is still giving an error!!

Comment: @dcclassics some null value is retrieved so its giving a null value pointer !!

Comment: Try a JSFiddle, so you can test and people can help you,. You can edit thisone: http://jsfiddle.net/eP8q9/